# Import a Third-Party Component (vue-color) in the custom Vue.js Component

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, color-picker

I recently started using Vue.js and I want to create simple TODO application. But I need to have opportunity to choose a color for my task in the input form. So, I've found a third-party library vue-color, but I don't know how to include it in my app with next structure based on webpack template:

```
../
  src
    components
      ProjectInput.vue
      ProjectItem.vue
      ProjectList.vue
      ColorPicker.vue
    App.vue
    main.js
```

Component **ProjectInput** has next definition of color component:

```
<template>
    ...
    <color-picker/>

<script>
  import ColorPicker from './ColorPicker'

  export default {
    components: {
      ColorPicker
    },
  ...
```

... and a simple component **ColorPicker.vue** from documentation:

```
<template>
  <div class="input-group color-picker-component">
     <chrome-picker></chrome-picker>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import { Chrome } from 'vue-color'
  export default {
   name: 'ColorPicker',
   components: {
     'chrome-picker': Chrome
   },
 }
</script>
```

It return an error when will render ProjectInput

```
 [Vue warn]: Error in data(): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'h' of undefined"
 found in
  ---> <Chrome> at src/components/Chrome.vue
   <ColorPicker> at src/components/ColorPicker.vue
     <ProjectInput> at src/components/ProjectInput.vue
       <ProjectList> at src/components/ProjectList.vue
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root>
```

I tried a different ways. I tried to import vue-color in main.js and use like **Vue.use(VueColor)** in order create component in ProjectInput like **var Chrome = VueColor.Crome** but it return an error VueColor is undefined

How to import it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vue-color` component can not find initial color. You should provide `v-model` or `:value/@input`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
     ChromeColor: VueColor.Chrome
  },
  data: {
    color: '#ff00ff'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-color/2.4.6/vue-color.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <chrome-color v-model="color"></chrome-color>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, thank you! Yes, you right I've missed v-model. Now it works like I wanted.